# Get the days name ie 'Mon' from a date ie '2020-05-07'

Tags: javascript

I have dates fetched from an API formatted like this 2020-05-07.

How is it possible format this to show the actual days. Example '2020-05-07' would be 'Thur'.

I would prefer to use JavaScript to achieve this rather than a library.

To recap I want dates formatted like this 2020-05-07 to be turned into day names - 'MON, TUE, WED, THUR, FRI, SAT, SUN'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var d = new Date("2020-05-07");
var dayName = days[d.getDay()];

console.log(dayName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways of doing it... here's 2 of them, without the need of any dependency

**method 1:** extract string

```js
new Date("2020-05-07") // Date
    .toString()        // "Thu May 07 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)"
    .substr(0, 3)      // "Thu"
```

**method 2:** using `getDay()`

the Javascript `Date` object actually [has a way to retrieve the week day](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) using `getDay()` but this will return a number from `0` to `6` where `0` is Sunday

```js
const weekDay = ['Sun', 'Mon', ... ]
weekDay[ new Date("2020-05-07").getDay() ]  // "Thu"
```

Comment: Hows your method 2 different from mine?

Comment: why does it have to be different? you wrote it first while I was writing my answer, though my answer is more complete and I wouldn't delete so everyone can also see it...

Comment: You dont need to add method 2 as it is already up there. And yes you answer is complete, it can be seen from upvotes and acceptance.